# When form refresh occure, multipart/form-data are lost

Tags: validation, asp.net-mvc-4

I have form with file input, but when model is not validated or throw an error I lost information about attachment and user need upload file again. Other inputs are okay, but files does not work.

**View**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Person", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.AttachmentFile)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.AttachmentFile, new { type = "file" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.AttachmentFile)

    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
}
```

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(CreateVM model)
{
                        try
                        {
                            if (ModelState.IsValid)
                            {
                              // adding to db
                            }
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            ModelState.AddModelError(String.Empty, String.Format("Error : {0}", ex.Message));
                        }

  return View(model);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Browsers prevent specifying a value on a file input field either with a value attribute or via JavaScript.

This is a security measure to prevent malicious code from setting a value (path) and accessing a local file.

Comment: Oh, thank you i was just starting to write an javascript :-))